# Printing in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I am having some difficulty printing a string in scheme after using a condition and get the following error:

```
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: #t
  arguments...:
```

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with it and would appreciate any help.

```
(define (neg int)
  (cond
    (((< int 0) (display "negative"))
     (* int (-1)))))
```

Comment: You should go back and read the documentation, familiarize yourself with Scheme syntax before starting to code. Currently, you're using brackets in the wrong places.

Comment: I have just started programming with scheme and found it a little challenging. However, I agree with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many brackets at the start of your condition; you need two, not three. Remember that in Scheme, if you surround something between `()` that becomes a function application! That's why this doesn't make sense: `(-1)`, because `-1` is not a function, it's a number. Also, what will you do if the value is not negative? You need to handle that case, too! Try this:

```
(define (neg int)
  (cond ((< int 0)
         (display "negative ")
         (* int -1)) ; or better: (- int)
        (else
         (display "positive ")
         int)))
```